# difference between out.println("<html>Hello World</html>") and out.println("Hello World")

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I don't have much knowledge in HTML. I am just starting to learn servlet and JSP. But why are we putting HTML tags in Servlet or JSP, when it gives the same result that is put in `out.println()`. If you cant understand my question what is the difference between `out.println("<html>Hello World</html>")` and `out.println("Hello World")`? Both gives the same output when the servlet is run.

Comment: that should be `<html><body>hello world</body></html>`

Comment: If you're starting out, I recommend against using servlets directly; they're much too low-level to do significant work in. Look at Spring MVC, which supports JSP and several other template systems (including Thymeleaf, which is my preference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference when you don't use html special commands, but if you like your text in different fonts, colours and sizes, maybe also have a hyper-link, then use html tags.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the type of document that you're returning.

```
 out.println("Hello World")
```

prints plain text, and

```
out.println("<html>Hello World</html>")
```

returns an HTML document.  It's up to the client's web browser to decide how to display it - I'd expect both to render the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can't see the difference until you open a source window.

```
out.println("Hello World")
```

is using `text/plain` content-type attribute, but you should set `text/html` if you are using html tags.

Use the `setContentType` method on the `ServletResponse` before obtaining any object (`Stream` or `Writer`) used for output, e.g.:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
```

If you use a `Writer`, the Servlet automatically takes care of the conversion from Java Strings to the encoding selected.